# executar arquivo shell no ubuntu pelo crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron

Estou tentando fazer um agendamento de tarefa no linux para executar um arquivo `sh`, porém, não executa pelo `crontab`, mas executa quando faço na mão.

Fiz um teste de agendamento para criar um arquivo texto, funciona, mas para executar o `sh` não.

Segue as configurações:

Configurações do /etc/crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/user/selamat.sh
```

Já tentei assim:

```
*/1 * * * * root sh /home/user/selamat.sh
```

E assim:

```
 */1 * * * * root (cd/home/user/ && ./selamat.sh >> Script.log 2>&1)
```

As configurações do script shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --info --text "SELAMAT";
```

Esse script abre um popup.

Comment: O arquivo tem permissão de execução? Se não possuir, dê o comando chmod +x nome_do_arquivo.

Comment: Já consultou os logs?

Comment: Há uma chance do zenity não estar sendo encontrado também. Normalmente é uma boa utilizar caminhos absolutos em comandos dentro de shell scripts.

Comment: Em algumas distros, existe uma opção de colocar uma espécie de `cron` _por usuário_, com um arquivo `cron` em algum lugar da `HOME` do usuário

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, deve ser dado permissão para executar o script (talvez já tenha feito).

```
chmod +x /home/user/selamat.sh
```

Coloque no crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/selamat.sh
```

Se quiser editar o arquivo do usuario atual da crontab. Pode ser permissão tbm.

```
crontab -e
```

Após feito isso, execute o comando:
    crontab /etc/crontab

Em seguida reiniciei o cron

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```

Nos retorne quando puder. ;)